# Failure provisioning a vm

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, sysprep

I have an on prem sysprepped vhd with which I am trying to create a vm in azure. I am running into all kinds of errors and I am solving one after the other. Now, I actually have an error which is not making any sense to me.

```
New-AzureRmVM : Long running operation failed with status 'Failed'.
StartTime: 4/10/2016 11:26:53 PM
EndTime: 4/10/2016 11:34:19 PM
OperationID: cf8fee0a-4f7b-4c85-8522-c0b47147eee8
Status: Failed
ErrorCode: NetworkingInternalOperationError
ErrorMessage: Unknown network allocation error.
At line:43 char:11
+ $result = New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Location $locatio ...
+~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo     : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmVM],       ComputeCloudException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.NewAzureVMCommand
```

Any kind of help is apreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share the code you are using?

Comment: @Miachel B. Thanks for the reply. I actually solved the problem. But since you replied, I just had to change the names of all those variables I was going to create (ip,domain name  etc.) I actually used the NIC for a different VM whichI thought I deleted it(but did not). And I was trying to assign that NIC to a new VM. Just, had to give new name to the NIC, ip, domain etc..